# sqlite query using java

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm working on shifts manager program which calculates monthly salary and etc.
the program based on SQLite database which keeps getting updated by the user input.
my question is , how can i use the SQLite function in java to retrieve information, lets say monthly salary in one command (i know i can use " select sum(tips) between date1 and date2",but how can i get the function result inside a variable?)
so far i've created a function which gets two dates and retrieves all the shifts salary between these dates and summarise them with ResultSet.

here's my code:

```
public static String tipsMade(String date1, String date2){
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String ans= null;
    int sum = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Gil\\test.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select tips from shifts where fulldate between "+"'"+date1+"'"+"and " +"'"+date2+"'"+ ";");
        while(rs.next()){
            sum += rs.getInt("tips");
        }
        ans = Integer.toString(sum);
        //

        //close connections and etc
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return ans;
    }
```

Comment: i just wonder how i can retrieve data from sqlite functions, as you can see the code is already written , just trying to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code.
 Note that in case you select the sum of the tips, the column name changes. You also get only one row with one column as your result, so you should not need the while loop anymore.

The sum of the tips is now saved in the variable `sum`

```
public static String tipsMade(String date1, String date2){
Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String ans= null;
int sum = 0;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Gil\\test.db");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    stmt = c.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select sum(tips) from shifts where fulldate between "+"'"+date1+"'"+"and " +"'"+date2+"'"+ ";");
    while(rs.next()){
        sum = rs.getInt("sum(tips)");
    }
    ans = Integer.toString(sum);
    //

    //close connections and etc
    stmt.close();
    c.commit();
    c.close();

} catch ( Exception e ) {
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    System.exit(0);
}
return ans;
}
```